# Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ado.net

```
Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating93D6F136794E0F2DED98BBB434C0AB6B1BABD9986CF045D207B1349AA5C562DE7F6768CC72494F822CD0E8B6D07104A542507F67E73B56FFE45CC4AB1D75F16F.GeneratedTextTransformation.DynamicTextTransformation.get_GenerationEnvironment()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating93D6F136794E0F2DED98BBB434C0AB6B1BABD9986CF045D207B1349AA5C562DE7F6768CC72494F822CD0E8B6D07104A542507F67E73B56FFE45CC4AB1D75F16F.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTransformation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating93D6F136794E0F2DED98BBB434C0AB6B1BABD9986CF045D207B1349AA5C562DE7F6768CC72494F822CD0E8B6D07104A542507F67E73B56FFE45CC4AB1D75F16F.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTemplating)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating93D6F136794E0F2DED98BBB434C0AB6B1BABD9986CF045D207B1349AA5C562DE7F6768CC72494F822CD0E8B6D07104A542507F67E73B56FFE45CC4AB1D75F16F.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating93D6F136794E0F2DED98BBB434C0AB6B1BABD9986CF045D207B1349AA5C562DE7F6768CC72494F822CD0E8B6D07104A542507F67E73B56FFE45CC4AB1D75F16F.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() LIBRARY C:\Users\JD\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\ProjectName\LIBRARY\DBModel.tt    1
```

What is the solution to this error?

Comment: Having the same issue on last VS2022 17.6.2

Comment: in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6. Utility.CS.ttinclude

`private DynamicTextTransformation(object instance)
{
    _instance = instance;
    Type type = _instance.GetType();
    _write = type.GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    _writeLine = type.GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    _generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment");
    _host = type.GetProperty("Host");
    _errors = type.GetProperty("Errors");
}`

Comment: This issue is utterly odd, and recent. It should be reopened. Redirecting to and old question with a myriad of answers is of little use.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me: https://gist.github.com/carloswm85/461df6ad36c96e69a9dab0d88f599d39

Comment: Ongoing problem. See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-import-anymore-tables-into-edmx/10368835 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance/10368943

Comment: The workaround described in this link worked for me: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Entity-Framework-Running-Transformation/10371307